# Android : Bluetooth accept() failed error

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am having an android application that connects with the pc. It workd on win xp but does not work with Win 7. And in windows 7, if i use a bluetooth dongle, it works, but it does not work withe the Bluetooth2.1 software in my laptop.

**i get this error**
accept() failed
04-07 14:58:56.354: E/BluetoothService.cpp(196): stopDiscoveryNative: D-Bus error in StopDiscovery: org.bluez.Error.Failed (Invalid discovery session)

04-07 14:58:56.362: E/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(196): onCreateDeviceResult: D-Bus error: org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists (Already Exists)

Code:

```
private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
```

// listen

```
    public AcceptThread() {
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;

        // Create a new listening server socket
        try {
            tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME, MY_UUID);
            //tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME, MY_UUID);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "listen() failed", e);
        }
        mmServerSocket = tmp;
    }
```

// connect

```
    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        mmDevice = device;
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;

        // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
        // given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);

            //tmp = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "create() failed", e);
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "BEGIN mAcceptThread" + this);
        setName("AcceptThread");
        BluetoothSocket socket = null;

        // Listen to the server socket if we're not connected
        while (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "accept() failed", e);
                break;
            }

            // If a connection was accepted
            if (socket != null) {
                synchronized (BluetoothService.this) {
                    switch (mState) {
                    case STATE_LISTEN:
                    case STATE_CONNECTING:
                        // Situation normal. Start the connected thread.
                        connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice());
                        break;
                    case STATE_NONE:
                    case STATE_CONNECTED:
                        // Either not ready or already connected. Terminate new socket.
                        try {
                            socket.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Could not close unwanted socket", e);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (D) Log.i(TAG, "END mAcceptThread");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: have to use Reflection

m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});

Comment: this was not exactly the answer... the problem is that the Windows 7 bluetooth stack does not provide spp drivers.. So we will have to use the bluetooth dongle which comes with the driver for it...